# While calculating timedelta i get the wrong values, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have the following sample datetime value.
Originated by the following line of code and string

```py
s = '2022-08-02T17:33:44.358Z'
s = pd.to_datetime(s)
# Print
Timestamp('2022-08-02 17:33:44.358000+0000', tz='UTC')
```

I also have a second string value converted to datetime

```py
s1 = '2022-08-02T17:33:44.600Z'
s1 = pd.to_datetime(s1)
# Print
Timestamp('2022-08-02 17:33:44.600000+0000', tz='UTC')
```

When I calculate the timedelta I get a weird result somethin way beyond the amount of seconds that I should get

```py
pd.Timedelta(s-s1).seconds
#This prints out
86399 seconds
```

Am I doing something wrong, I really don't understand why there is so many seconds

Comment: @GodWin this is not the issue, using `second` is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to pass the difference to `pd.Timedelta` and importantly use **[`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html)**:

```
(s-s1).total_seconds()
```

output: `-0.242`